# SharePoint hosted app REST API

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint-online

So, I've been going through every resource i can find, have tried almost every piece of code I could find on here and using the Microsoft Documentation. I can not figure out that I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to update a field called DispatchStatus in a list called Schedule Orders using REST, but no matter what I try I either get an undefined result in the success function with the field not being updated or I get

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"404 NOT FOUND","statusText":"NOT FOUND"}
```

returned as an error.

here is the code I'm using:

```
function updateDelivery(id) {
    var url = "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Scheduled Orders')/items(" + id + ")"
    var itemMetadata = {
      '__metadata': {
          'type': getListItemType('Scheduled Orders')
      },
      'DispatchStatus': document.getElementById(id).value
  };
  updateL(url, itemMetadata, checkresult);
}
function updateItem(url, itemMetadata, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        data: JSON.stringify(itemMetadata),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        headers: {
            'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
            'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'IF-MATCH': '*'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
function getListItemType(name) {
    var ret = "";
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + name + "')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName"
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ret = data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName
        },
        error: function (error) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });    
    return ret;
}
```

This seems like it should be a simple task, am I missing required data? Do I need to copy over all the previous data in the item? Or do I need to go about updating a list item differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that it was working the entire time but IE apparently has issues recognizing

```
var a = b = c = d = "";
```

insted of

```
var a = "";
var b = "";
var c = "";
var d = "";
```

So in IE, which is the browser I have to develop this for, it looked like it wasn't working because that value that was being updated was not being picked up. When I looked at the app in Chrome and noticed that everything was working i realized it was not my REST call but instead a problem with the browser. I tracked it down and now it finally works in IE. Yet another thing that IE causes to break but everything else on all other browsers works just fine. I would like to know why everything else was working just fine except `var c` in IE. For the life of me i can not figure out why just that one variable was somehow unable to be assigned a value and only in IE?